# White space at the bottom of div caused by Hide/Show content

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need help with trying to stretch a scrolling div to 100% the height of it's parent container, but the **Hide/Show content** creates a whitespace at the bottom of the div.

Here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fkvftff2/1/

[image]

**UPDATE**
This is my issue, when you stretch the window out and press the hide button it leaves a white space at the bottom of the div.

The culprit is the **toggle button**. The display block and display hidden seem to hide the white div content, but it still affects the div with a white space at the bottom.

If you look down here this is what I want to stretch the green scrolling div the entire height of the parent container no matter how 
I stretch it or how I hide or show content.

[image]

Here's the html in question:

```
    <!--Center-->
    <div class="center">

     <!--Feed Content-->
     <div id="feed-content">
     <div id="networkfeed" class="feedpagetab activefeed">

     <input type="checkbox" id="filterbutton" role="button">
     <label for="filterbutton" onclick=""><span class="filterswitch">Show Me</span><span class="filterswitch">Hide Me</span> 
      </label>
                <br />
                <br />
      <div class="borderline"></div>

       <section class="filtercontent"></section><!--Filtercontent ends here-->

        <div id="contentSection">
        <div id="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ius an dolorum lucilius sensibus, et sint graeco nec. Iudico atomorum eam eu. Nec equidem conceptam id. Cum velit viris voluptua an. Sea eu harum eirmod eloquentiam, quaestio complectitur voluptatibus in nam, an dicam platonem adolescens has. Te usu esse idque, no modo tractatos sed. Vero audire sapientem an sit, homero recteque pri in, vis at vidit admodum. Ex quo doctus eleifend contentiones, vis odio mucius tritani ut. Id cetero nostrud dissentiunt mel. Docendi scaevola vis ei. Vel et ponderum electram expetendis, cum cu quaestio definitionem, etiam ponderum vix ei. Ut his feugait assentior philosophia, atqui definitionem at mei. Liber sonet dictas ea has, nec odio fabellas ei. Vel oratio quodsi in, duo minim admodum ea. Pri id dolorum indoctum, vim at alia tritani. No pro esse error solet, vix quis prodesset ei. Tollit accommodare vis at, sed in tamquam prompta dolorem. Nam solum definitionem an, dicta nostrum adversarium ne nec. Eu docendi nominavi similique pri. Qui an natum tamquam, dictas invenire mei id. Cu omittam insolens rationibus ius, dicunt inciderint cum ea. Est vero dolorem et, assum antiopam mea ne. Te vel choro audiam, eum equidem nostrum ex. Ea nam offendit definitiones. In etiam debitis similique cum. Ius regione incorrupte te, utinam ceteros an has, omnium concludaturque cum eu. Eu sumo adhuc ius. Quo choro quodsi latine an. Nonumy deleniti duo ex, fastidii menandri accusata ut mea, ad minimum omnesque quo. Cum in molestiae mediocritatem. Partiendo voluptaria cum te. Illud reque convenire duo et, audiam denique consectetuer mei te. Bonorum fabellas interpretaris mel ad. Eu sanctus nominavi ius, oratio vocibus indoctum ea eos. Et nisl doming vituperatoribus vis. Ullum percipit inciderint ei duo, ex usu stet essent. Quis errem legere ex quo, usu ludus decore ut, vix cetero convenire honestatis et. Mucius nusquam platonem per et, cu mei nibh erant inermis. Ne quo erant commodo sadipscing. Mei delenit tibique aliquando no, vim ex omnis vocibus scriptorem. Reque aperiam hendrerit et per, sit suas vivendo corrumpit in. Ius ei falli doming periculis. Nam quis iuvaret at. Impedit minimum similique ei pri, graeco interpretaris eu ius, dolor probatus scribentur in qui. Duo aliquam omittam voluptaria no. Vel enim hendrerit persecuti ne. Sed no idque fastidii neglegentur. Everti accusamus deterruisset eos ut, an sea feugiat alienum rationibus. Duo ex graece gloriatur, lorem appetere inimicus sed eu, autem sanctus in ius. No lorem altera qualisque eum, id eum labore necessitatibus, sit no diceret pertinax partiendo. At pri hinc solet voluptatum, ut debitis intellegam vix. Decore ridens comprehensam sea id, ius aperiam delicatissimi no. Quas molestie ei his, in has augue equidem adipisci.
         </div><!--End Content-->             
         </div><!--End Content Section-->



      </div> <!--End Network feed-->
    </div><!--End Feed Content-->
</div><!--End Center-->
```

Here's the css:

```
.center {
    overflow:hidden;
    min-height:100%;
    float:none;
    background-color:#FFF;
    color:#999;
    position:relative;
}

#contentSection {
    overflow-y:scroll;
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:green;
}

/*----- Show me Button-----*/
 .filtercontent {
    margin: 0;
    position:relative;
    border-bottom:#000 solid 1px;
    padding: 0;
    height:170px;
    margin-top:5px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    color:#000;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.feedpagetab > section:first-of-type {
    float: right;
    width: 62.5%;
}
.feedpagetab > section:last-of-type {
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden;
}
.feedpagetab {
    -webkit-transition: .125s linear;
    -moz-transition: .125s linear;
    -ms-transition: .125s linear;
    -o-transition: .125s linear;
    transition: .125s linear;
}
#filterbutton[type=checkbox] {
    border: 0;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    height: 1px;
    width: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
[for="filterbutton"] {
    position: absolute;
    top:4px;
    padding: 0;
    left: 5%;
    width: 80px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 4px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color: #555;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #DDD;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, "Sans Serif";
    font-size: 13px;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 1px 0px #FFF;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 1px 0px #FFF;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 1px 0px #FFF;
    background: #EEE;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #F9F9F9 0%, #DDD 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #F9F9F9), color-stop(100%, #DDD));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #F9F9F9 0%, #DDD 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #F9F9F9 0%, #DDD 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #F9F9F9 0%, #DDD 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#F9F9F9', endColorstr='#DDD', GradientType=0);
    background: linear-gradient(top, #F9F9F9 0%, #DDD 100%);
}
[for="filterbutton"]:hover {
    color: #444444;
    font-weight:bold;
    border-color: #BBB;
    background: #CCC;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #F9F9F9 0%, #CCC 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #F9F9F9), color-stop(100%, #CCC));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #F9F9F9 0%, #CCC 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #F9F9F9 0%, #CCC 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #F9F9F9 0%, #CCC 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#F9F9F9', endColorstr='#CCC', GradientType=0);
}
[for="filterbutton"] span.filterswitch:last-of-type {
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden;
}
#filterbutton[type=checkbox]:checked {
    color:#FFA317;
}
#filterbutton[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .filtercontent {
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
    width: 100%;
}
#filterbutton[type=checkbox]:checked ~[for="filterbutton"] span.filterswitch:first-of-type {
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden;
}
#filterbutton[type=checkbox]:checked ~[for="filterbutton"] span.filterswitch:last-of-type {
    color:#3CC;
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
}
.borderline {
    width:100%;
    border-bottom:#000 solid 1px;
    height:0px;
}
.filtercontent {
    margin-left:29%;
}
```

And this is the javascript for the resizing scrolling div

```
var height = 0;
var minHeight = 200;
$("#content").parent().siblings().each(function () {
    height = height + $(this).height();
});
// for when the document is loaded
$(document).ready(function () {
    var windowheight = $(window).height() - 100;
    $(".center").height();
    $(".center").css("min-height", minHeight + height + "px");
    var newHeight = $(".center").height() - height;
    $("#contentSection").css("height", newHeight - 0 + "px");
});

// for the window resize
$(window).resize(function () {
    var windowheight = $(window).height() - 100;
    $(".center").height(windowheight);
    $("#content").height($("#content").parent().height());
    var newHeight = $(".center").height() - height;
    $("#contentSection").css("height", newHeight - 0 + "px");
});
```

As you can see from the fiddle when you vertically stretch the div, and press the button to show the content it shifts a whitespace at the bottom of the scrolling div. My goal is to remove all whitespace from the scrolling div area. So the scrolling div takes 100% of the height and resizes accordingly.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: [Like this?](http://jsfiddle.net/ImagineStudios/fkvftff2/2/)

Comment: I still get the same result. Try it out for yourself. Stretch the height of the window almost all the way, then click the Show me buttpm followed by the hide me button. Now when the content is hidden you will see a white space at the bottom.

Comment: Is this what you are trying to achieve? http://jsfiddle.net/fkvftff2/6/

if not can you add an image of what the final result should look like?

Comment: It's close, but im trying to prevent white space at the bottom from pushing the scrolling div up. There should be no white space whatsoever. I added an image above.

Answer (score 0):

i think you have a div more than you need. Try deleting #contentSection, and implementing all of its code in #content.

Honestly if you're trying to hide the whole text on the click of  a button, then try rewriting the style of the content text. like adjust opacity:1 to opacity:0 on the click of the button.

Comment: Removing the div #contentselection does nothing. The problem lies on the #filtercontent, #filterbutton, and .feedpagetab, thats what causes the white space at the bottom. If you remove those divs and the input everything will work as inteded ex: http://jsfiddle.net/tyy9gmxy/ Unfortunately, I need the hide/show button to work as well :/

Comment: your javascript and general code is confusing and way too overcomplicated. All you need is a counter on your checkbox or button, and if it's divisible by two, opacity = 0, else opacity = 1. Also the fact that deleting #contentselection doesn't change anything shows how useless that div is, so don't use it. What you're trying to achieve is done in so many more different ways that are less complicated...

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle on how to use opacity to show or hide the content? I'm not familiar with the js way of hiding and showing content. As for the layout I'm using is called the holygrail, and it's the only layout than can maintain a flexible width when stretching the window, but if you have a better alternative please demonstrate.

Comment: Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VerdeletG/o0sxjwLm/4/). adapt it to your content! It works with visibility=hidden/visible or opacity=0/1, and in order for the content to disappear and everything else take the now empty space display=block/none works too

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7emf2y7s/ I changed it to display none and display block, however I get the same results. Is there a way to remove the div #content completely when you press the button and not just make it dissapear but still affect the container?

Comment: uhm... how do you mean? like you replace the text area with the filter area? yeah that is possible, look it up! I think you can accomplish this by giving the filter display:none and text display:block, and onclick switch the displays of each. it'd be the same code as i showed you but for two vars, one for content and the other for content2, and alternate them! so if content2=block, then content=none.

Comment: I added a picture to clearly demonstrate what I mean. I want to stretch the green scrolling div the entire height of its parent container, but keep it visible at all tiimes. And when you press the show button I want the green div to shift down, but fill the remainder of the contrainer. No white spaces at the bottom.

Comment: max height for the parent container?

Comment: Max height won't work with 100% height. I'm trying to keep it fluid so that it stretches, is there a way to keep the bottom of the scrolling div at the bottom?

Comment: use the toggle! you can cheat it! when the text is height:100% the filter is invisible, and if the thing is visible, make height 80%....

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/z0Lzeppj/ Check this out. IF you can get the toggle content to work on this fiddle. It will be perfect.

Answer (score 0):

To make a couple of notes, I do not know what the feed is all about and the center, but I have edited your code ever so slightly and added a toggle. [Check out my Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VerdeletG/o0sxjwLm/4/).

Basically, I focused on your content section. here is your new HTML for it:

```
  <button onclick="toggleContent()">Toggle Visibility</button>

  <div id="contentWrapper">
    <div id="content">
      text goes here. longer version in JSFiddle
     </div>             
  </div>
```

The corresponding JS is here:

```
function toggleContent() {
  // Get the DOM reference
  var e = document.getElementById("content");
  // Toggle 
  e.style.opacity == "1" ? e.style.opacity = "0" : 
  e.style.opacity = "1"; 
}
```

which basically says if the opacity is 1 when the button is pressed, make it 0, otherwise keep it one.
Here is the CSS for your part (you don't need a div for a top border. Just use border-top. also, to center, make a container with width=100% and then your class inside it give it a width and have margin:auto)

```
#contentWrapper{
 width:100%;
 position:relative;
 border-top:1px solid black;
 padding-top:10px;
 margin-top:10px;
}

#content {
 overflow-y:scroll;
 background-color:green;
 height:400px;
 width:500px;
 margin:auto;
}
```

Hope this clears some stuff up!

Comment: For some reason when I implement your code into my jfiddle the opacity hack doesnt work. Try it out for yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/z6eap1hf/ The Content div is visible at all times, and cant be toggled on or off.

Comment: two things. first in your javascript code, where you have getElementById("content") change it to ("content2"). second, in your html, for <div id="content2"> add the opacity style to it in the html, like so: <div id="content2" style="opacity:1;">

Comment: I want to toggle the white space on or off, not the content. Check out the initial fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/fkvftff2/1/. As you can see it toggles the white space on or off.

Comment: ok i'm lost. you're trying to cover up the content with white space... why would you not just... you know... make it invisible...?

Comment: The white space is supposed to contain a filter. So I'm trying to make a dropdown filter when you press the show button the filter pops out. You get it?  http://jsfiddle.net/fkvftff2/7/ I updated the original jsfiddle to avoid confusion. I gave the hide/show a black background.

Comment: all i could say is position absolute, and then place it absolutely over the area where the text is. OR have the filter below the text, and have the text over it instead. either way, you're code is confusing. Like that button is annoying. you can also innerhtml the button text with javascript, so that onToggle you can also change the button title. I'll link a javascript for you